# Whats the best (easiest) way to make an animation like this?

Tags: animation

[This is the animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-5OX7CO26c)

I know absolutely nothing about video editing and animation, so whats the easiest way to make something like that, and how long would it take?

Thanks a lot!